# Get weekly website visit count and show in chart js in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to count weekly visitors of website and show in chart js.

My code to obtain the information

```html
$visits = Visit::select([
            DB::raw('DATE(visit_date) AS date'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(fingerprint) AS count')
        ])->whereBetween('visit_date', [Carbon::now()->subDays(7), Carbon::now()])
            ->groupBy('date')
            ->orderBy('date','ASC')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
        $visitChartByDay = array();
        foreach ($visits as $data) {
            $date = date('M j', strtotime($data['date']));
            $visitChartByDay[$date] = $data['count'];
        }
        $date = new Carbon();
        for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
            $dateString = $date->format('M j');
            if (!isset($visitChartByDay[$dateString])) {
                $visitChartByDay[$dateString] = 0;
            }
            $date->subDay();

        }
        dd($visitChartByDay);
        return response()->json($visitChartByDay);
```

With this query I get the data but I am not getting in asc order. When I dd the data it is like this,
[image]

I want the data in order (oct 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14). How can I achieve that.

Comment: try  with `sortKeys()` function

Comment: @noor can you please suggest example?

Comment: `$visitChartByDay->sortKeys()` try it .. i think it will work

Comment: or `$collection = collect($visitChartByDay)` then `$collection->sortKeys()`

Comment: I get this error Call to a member function sortKeys() on array.

Comment: Now I get this   #items: array:7 [▼
    "Oct 10" => 0
    "Oct 11" => 0
    "Oct 12" => 0
    "Oct 13" => 1
    "Oct 14" => 3
    "Oct 8" => 0
    "Oct 9" => 0

Comment: then `$collection->all();`

Comment: sortkeys add the two values in date like 10=1+0=1, 11=1+1=2 and it sort like this.

Comment: $collection->all() is same as my above picture.

Comment: `$collection = collect($visitChartByDay)` then `$collection = $collection->sortKeys()` then `$collection->all()`

Comment: The result is again same as $collection->sortKeys()

Comment: try this `$collection ->values()->all()`..

Comment: It gives this data array:7 [▼
  0 => 0
  1 => 0
  2 => 0
  3 => 1
  4 => 3
  5 => 0
  6 => 0
] which is wrong data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223043/discussion-between-noor-and-sd077).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try something like this ? Just make sure you put same date format in your select query as it is on this line `$date->format()`

```
$lastSevenDays = CarbonPeriod::create(Carbon::now()->subDays(6), Carbon::now());
foreach ($lastSevenDays as $date) {
    $dateCount[$date->format("M j")] = 0;
}

foreach ($visits as $countPerDay) {
    $dateCount[$countPerDay->date] = $countPerDay->count;
}
```

Comment: Ok i will try it.

Comment: You leave $visits as it is ( maybe remove toArray() ) and below that you can put code I posted in answer. Just make sure date formats are same

Comment: What is $dateCount here?

Comment: It works but how can I make date formats to be $date->format("M,j")in select query

Comment: You can use `SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2017-10-15", "%b %d")` to get same format I think

Answer (score 0):

I am facing your problem, but I managed to solve it

```html
$visits= Visit::select([
            DB::raw('DATE(visit_date) AS date'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(fingerprint) AS count')
        ])->whereBetween('visit_date', [Carbon::now()->subDays(7), Carbon::now()])
            ->groupBy('date')
            ->orderBy('date','DESC')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
            $visitsChartByDay= array();
        $lastSevenDays = CarbonPeriod::create(Carbon::now()->subDays(6), Carbon::now());
        foreach ($visits as $data) {
              foreach ($lastSevenDays as $date) {
                $dateString = $date->format('M j');
                if (!isset($visitsChartByDay[$dateString])) {
                    $visitsChartByDay[$dateString] = 0;
                }
            }
            if (isset($visitsChartByDay[$dateString])) {
                $date = date('M j', strtotime($data['date']));
                $visitsChartByDay[$date] = $data['count'];
            }

        }
        return $visitsChartByDay;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrrOo.png)